# why does map function changes the value of the input array in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, dictionary

why does map function changes the value of the input array in perl?
To illustrate,

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl


use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;


my @words = <DATA>;

# want to have another array that contains the each word in reverse order
my @reverse_words =  map {  $_   =  scalar reverse $_    } @words;

say $words[0]; # want to check the content of first element of original array
say $reverse_words[0]; # new 



__DATA__
aarhus
aaron
ababa
aback
```

But this prints

```
 $perl findPalindrome.pl

suhraa

suhraa
```

Why is the original array altered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you asked it to by modifying `$_`.

You want

```
my @reverse_words = map { scalar reverse $_ } @words;
```

Comment: so you don't deal with the copied version of the element of the array? isn't this dangerous?

Comment: I have no idea what that means

Comment: Sorry. I meant this: $_ is a pointer to a each element in the words, rather than a copied element? so by $_ = scalar reverse $_, you are effectively changing the element in words, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's an alias (or reference, in C++ terms).